# Conditionally change dataframe index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi index panadas dataframe like the one below. This is just one example of the problem I have. In reality, this dataframe could be very large and contains many occurances of this problem.

In the first row, `index2` has a value of `2`and in the last row `index1` has a value of `2`. This shouldn't be the case. As a results, I need to change the `index1`of the last row to `1` so that all rows are part of `index1` `1`.

```
                 given_name
 index1   index2    
 664627    766206         1
          1297240         1
          1429530         1
 569874    396418         1
 766206   1429531         1
 169874   3697813         1
 123456   1598742         1
 1598742  19543864        1
```

the desired output should look like:

```
                 given_name
 index1   index2    
 664627    766206         1
          1297240         1
          1429530         1
          1429531         1
 569874    396418         1
 169874   3697813         1
 123456   1598742         1
         19543864         1
```

Ideally, the solution should be vectorised and quick. I doesn't have to use the index. the dataframe could use `reset_index()` and work as them as columns then reset the columns back as indexs.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: I have a input dataframe that is similar to the first shown. The output should look like the the second one. This is just one case so it needs to be a general solution. Ill clear things up.

Comment: Do you need `df = df.rename({2:1}, level=0)` ?

Comment: @AurenFerguson there are a **BUNCH** of ways to get the final result.  In order to narrow down what to do, we need a rule or method that helps clarify **WHY** the 2 should be a 1.

Comment: I'm using the `recordlinkage` python module for identity resolution and it uses multi-indexing but doesn't do it fully correctly. i.e on row one it matches `1 & 2` and on the fourth row it matches `2 & 5`. Currently it doesn't realise that `1 & 5`are also a match. There in row 4 `index1` needs to be changed to `2` and in the last row `index1` should be changed to `6`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: 
   ...: string1 = """index1,index2,given_name
   ...: 1,2,1
   ...: 1,3,1
   ...: 1,4,1
   ...: 2,5,1
   ...: 6,7,1
   ...: 6,8,1
   ...: 7,9,1
   ...: 9,10,1
   ...: 10,11,1
   ...: 5,12,1
   ...: 12,13,1
   ...: 13,14,1"""
   ...: 
   ...: df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(string1), index_col=[0,1])
   ...: 

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
               given_name
index1 index2            
1      2                1
       3                1
       4                1
2      5                1
6      7                1
       8                1
7      9                1
9      10               1
10     11               1
5      12               1
12     13               1
13     14               1


def find_fixing_rows(df):

    df = df.reset_index()

    # getting indexes of zeroth  and first index
    level_zero_indexs = np.unique(df.index1.values)
    level_one_indexs = np.unique(df.index2.values)

    # finding indexes that appear in both levels, these are ones that need fixing
    intersect_index = np.intersect1d(level_zero_indexs, level_one_indexs)

    # getting rows that need to be fixed using intersect_index
    df_need_fix = df[df.index2.isin(intersect_index)]

    return df_need_fix


def combine_missed_matches(df):

    #df_need_fix = find_fixing_rows(df)

    df = df.reset_index()

    # getting indexes of zeroth  and first index
    level_zero_indexs = np.unique(df.index1.values)
    level_one_indexs = np.unique(df.index2.values)

    # finding indexes that appear in both levels, these are ones that need fixing
    intersect_index = np.intersect1d(level_zero_indexs, level_one_indexs)

    # getting rows that need to be fixed using intersect_index
    df_need_fix = df[df.index2.isin(intersect_index)]

    # joining  fixed rows onto original dataframe to allow changing of indexes
    df_with_need_fix_join = pd.merge(df,
                                     df_need_fix,
                                     left_on='index1',
                                     right_on='index2',
                                     how='left')

    # logic to swap indexs
    df_with_need_fix_join['index1_x'] = np.where(df_with_need_fix_join.index1_y.notnull(),
                                                 df_with_need_fix_join.index1_y,
                                                 df_with_need_fix_join.index1_x)

    # dropping columns, renaming and tidying
    df_with_need_fix_join = df_with_need_fix_join.drop(['index1_y',
                                                        'index2_y',
                                                        'given_name_y'],
                                                       axis=1)

    df_with_need_fix_join = df_with_need_fix_join.rename(columns={
                                'index1_x' : 'index1',
                                'index2_x' : 'index2',
                                'given_name_x' : 'given_name'
                            })

    df_with_need_fix_join.index1 = df_with_need_fix_join.index1.astype(np.int)

    df_with_need_fix_join = df_with_need_fix_join.set_index(['index1', 'index2'])

    return  df_with_need_fix_join

def fix_missing_matches(df, condition=True):

    while condition:

        condition = find_fixing_rows(df).shape[0] > 0
        df = combine_missed_matches(df)

    df = df.sort_index()

    return df

In [4]: df_fix = fix_missing_matches(df)
   ...: 
   ...: df_fix
   ...: 
Out[4]: 
               given_name
index1 index2            
1      2                1
       3                1
       4                1
       5                1
       12               1
       13               1
       14               1
6      7                1
       8                1
       9                1
       10               1
       11               1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe need [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for first level of `MultiIndex`, convert it to `Series` by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) for possible replace `NaN`s by forward filling created by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
idx1 = df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series()
idx2 = df.index.get_level_values(1)
idx = idx1.mask(idx1.isin(idx2)).ffill().astype(int)

df = df.set_index([idx, idx2])
print (df)
               given_name
index1 index2            
1      2              1.0
       3              0.0
       4              1.0
       5              0.5
6      7              1.0
       8              1.0
       9              0.0
```

Comment: Setting the indexes isn't the problem. Finding which indexes to be done needs to be found programatically as this is done thousands of times. Only certain indexes in `index1`are changed and that condition is when a value  `index2` appears in `index1`.

Comment: @AurenFerguson - Can you check now?

Comment: That solves it for this example alright. I'll test it on the larger dataset now and let you know. Thanks

Comment: This only works if the index is in sequence like in the example above. In my actual data, the indexes aren't sequential. Ill update my example now.

Comment: I don't think `ffill`or `bfill` are appropriate because the rows aren't always next to each other. they can be separated by thousands of rows. Although, I'm open to correction.

Comment: @Auren Ferguson How working first step `df = df. sort_index(ascending= False)`? I am offline now, on phone only, so cannot test.

Comment: yes, but there is no natural order to the indexes so sorting wont help. A link needs be be created between the indexes that need changing.

Comment: @AurenFerguson - I just test it and why `766206   1429531         1` has to be in first group like `664627    1429531         1`? What is reason?